# filtering an element from object array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object something like below

```
Object[0]

canUpload:false
canBeRemoved:true
  type:Object
    allowMultiple:false
    deleted:false
    key:"testValue"

Object[1]
canUpload:true
canBeRemoved:true
 type:Object
   allowMultiple:false
   deleted:false
   key:"testValue2"
```

I want to remove an elements from array which contains key:testValue

```
var myValues = this.testData.data3;

        if(!this.testData.canDownload){
  myValues= myValues.filter(function(value){
                    if(!value.canUpload)
                        return value.type.key==='testValue';
                else return false;
                });
```

But its not removing .Whats the right way to do it?
Here is the full code .I can see myValues array of size 2 .If i print myValues after if block its empty.
Code pen:http://codepen.io/developer301985/pen/woGBNg

Comment: Is it JavaScript?

Comment: `return value.type.key === 'testValue1'`

Comment: What is expected result of of `value.canUpload` at `if` condition?

Comment: if  value.canUpload= false In the array I want to upload.In developer console I dont see execution entering  that point if(!value.canUpload)

Comment: In this case object[0] should be removed

Comment: Where is `this.testData.canDownload` defined? Where `value.type.key==='testValue';` is `true`, the element would not be removed from array. `return value.type.key!=='testValue';`

Comment: Sorry now it should be clear this.testData is global variable and   `var myValues = this.testData.data3;`

Answer (score 1):

If your want to filter your array on the basis of two conditions:

- `canUpload` attr is false
- `type.key` is equal to **'testValue'**

so you may want to `return false` in case of `canUpload` is true to be as follow:

```
myValues= myValues.filter(function(value) {
  if(!value.canUpload)
    return value.type.key === 'testValue';
  else return false;
});
```

Otherwise, you just want to filter on `type.key` is equal to **'testValue'**, so it will be as follow:

```
myValues= myValues.filter(function(value) {
  return value.type.key === 'testValue';
});
```

Comment: myValues is empty after outer if block. Not sure If I am doing right

Comment: Make sure `myValues` is parsed as array of objects, also if you could get your code on Codepen to clarify your case more, it'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

Note, if the callback function you passed into filter returns true, the element will be kept rather than removed. So in your case, you should return false when the value is `testValue`.

If I understand you correctly, you want to remove item with `value.canUpload==false` AND `type.key === 'testValue'`. Then the negate is `value.canUpload || value.type.key !== 'testValue'`

```
var myValues = this.testData.data3;

if (!this.testData.canDownload) {
    myValues = myValues.filter(function(value) {
        return value.canUpload || value.type.key !== 'testValue';
    });
}
```

Let me know whether it works :)